# Filtering sequences in fasta file for record_id using Python

Tags: python, filtering, bioinformatics, biopython

I have fastx_collapser outputs, like this:

```
>14-1677
GTGGCTTGTAGGCGATAAACATGATGCATTGCACCTGCCTGACGTTGTCG
>15-1573
GGCAGAGAGAAGCATAAAACCTTCATACAAATTTAGTTATTCACCAAGTT
>6265153-1
GTGTATATTTTCTATCATCCTCTTTCTTCCCATATCTTATGTCACTGTTG
>6265154-1
GTCATCATCATACTCATCAGAATCCCAATATTCGTTTGGATATTCAAGCG
```

The first line represent the id of each sequences (>id) and the occurrences (-occurrences).The second line is the sequence of each read.

I would like to filter reads based on occurrences, I would like to maintain in an output file all the reads that have occurrences 1, and in an other output file all the remaining reads.

I'm trying this code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
input_file = "prova.fasta"
output_file1 = "prova_filt_singl.fasta"
output_file2 = "prova_filt_Nosingl.fasta"
id_index = ("")

records = (r for r in SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fasta")if id_index=="-1" in r.id.upper())
count = SeqIO.write(records, output_file1, "fasta")

records = (r for r in SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fasta")if id_index!="-1" in r.id.upper())
count = SeqIO.write(records, output_file2, "fasta")

print("Saved %i records from %s to %s" % (count, input_file, output_file1))
print("Saved %i records from %s to %s" % (count, input_file, output_file2))
```

I have a lot of problem:
It maintains also occurrences different from 1 and I don't have anything in the output_file2. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `id_index` but never actually assigning any values to it, which would be difficult since `tuples` are immutable http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm.

Your first file is always empty because the expression `id_index=="-1"` is always `False` and the second file gets all entries because `id_index!="-1"` is always `True`.

Changing these lines to:

```
records = (r for r in SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fasta") if r.id.endswith('-1'))
```

resp. `if not r.....` should give you the desired results.